# Python TimedRotatingFileHandler overwrites logs

Tags: python, logging

I setup `TimedRotatingFileHandler` like that:

```
import logging as logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import os
import time

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# new file every minute
rotation_logging_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('logs/log', 
                               when='m', 
                               interval=1, 
                               backupCount=5)
rotation_logging_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

format = u'%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(filename)s:%(lineno)d\t%(message)s'
rotation_logging_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(format))
rotation_logging_handler.suffix = '%Y-%m-%d'

logger.addHandler(rotation_logging_handler)
```

Usage:

```
logger.logging.info('Service started at port %s', config.get_param('port'))

while True:
    time.sleep(21)
    logger.logging.info('Now time is {}'.format(time.time()))
```

I expected that every minute new messages from `logs/log` had to append to existing log file for current date. Instead it every minute messages from `logs/log` overwrote existing log file for current date.

What should I do to reach that behaviour?

PS: After small research I found that `TimedRotatingFileHandler` in the `doRollover` method deletes existing log file and creates new file. So first solution is to create new handler derived from `TimedRotatingFileHandler` 
 which creates new file (with some index for example) insted of deleting existing log file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very much possible to change the filenames when they are rotated to anything you want by overrding the [rotation_filename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.BaseRotatingHandler.rotation_filename) method of the [BaseRotatingHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#baserotatinghandler) class and setting it to an appropriate callable.

Here is a very trivial example of doing the same, but you can tweak it to suit your needs.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import datetime as dt

def filer(self):
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    return 'file.txt'+now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")


logger = logging.getLogger()
rotating_file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename="/Users/rbhanot/file.txt",
                                                 when='S',
                                                 interval=2,
                                                 backupCount=5)
rotating_file_handler.rotation_filename = filer
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(name)s:%(levelname)s - %(message)s')
rotating_file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(rotating_file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.info("hello")
```

Here is the output of

```
❯ ls file*
file.txt  file.txt2020-10-06_13:12:13  file.txt2020-10-06_13:12:15  file.txt2020-10-06_13:13:45
```

Comment: This answer is not working... your `filer()` is not correct, it should take as an argument the original rolled file name and modified it, for example: `def filer(file_name): return file_name+".log"`

Comment: That is very much specific to your implementation, the gist of my answer is how to use `rotation_filename`, and not to go into specific implementation.

Comment: Ok, I recheck the error, I'm using a `Windows` machine and therefore one cannot create file name with `:` in it, so please note that for this code to work need to make sure the file name return from `filer` function is right for the OS. A side note: the use of hard coded `file.txt` name in `filer` function is not generic you should use: `return self+now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: rotating_file_handler.rotation_filename = filer is one way to do it. Based on the reference you cited, they recommend setting the callback with' rotating_file_handler.namer = filer'. 'rotation_filename()' calls 'namer'.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):

> The system will save old log files by appending extensions to the
>   filename. The extensions are date-and-time based, using the strftime
>   format `%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S` or a leading portion thereof, depending on
>   the rollover interval.

In other words: **by modifying suffix *you* are breaking the rollover**. Just leave it at default and python will create the files called:

- `logs/log2018-02-02-01-30`
- `logs/log2018-02-02-01-31`
- `logs/log2018-02-02-01-32`
- `logs/log2018-02-02-01-33`
- `logs/log2018-02-02-01-34`

And after this (if `backupCount=5`) it will delete the `-30` one and create the `-35`.

If you instead want to have names like :

- `logs/log2018-02-02-01.0`
- `logs/log2018-02-02-01.1`
- `logs/log2018-02-02-01.2`
- `logs/log2018-02-02-01.3`
- `logs/log2018-02-02-01.4`

Where `0` is the newest one and `.4` is the oldest one, then yes, that handler has not been designed to do that.

Comment: It's one of the possible solutions but I need indexed files so it's not working for me. As you can see in the my answer I found another possible solution for that.

Comment: @feeeper Trying to abuse a class to do something that it was not designed to do is usually not the right way forward.

Comment: As I can see at Python's Docs it is a right way to do this https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-a-rotator-and-namer-to-customize-log-rotation-processing

Comment: How is it an abuse of the class if what's @feeeper doing is using the callbacks or methods (i.e. rotator, namer) as documented and provided by the class to customize for his needs? Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-a-rotator-and-namer-to-customize-log-rotation-processing

Answer (score 1):

After little bit more researching I found `BaseRotatingHandler.namer` attribute usage in the [`BaseRotatingHandler.rotation_filename` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/aa0735f597b072c0eb00404c4d7df359ddc26755/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L74):

> The default implementation calls the 'namer' attribute of the handler, if it's callable, passing the default name to it. If the attribute isn't callable (the default is None), the name is returned unchanged.

So as a solution I implemented my own `namer` function that got `filename` and returned new `filename` with my template:

- `20181231.log`
- `20181231.0.log`
- `20181231.1.log`
- etc.

Full example:

```
import logging as logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import os
import time


def get_filename(filename):
    # Get logs directory
    log_directory = os.path.split(filename)[0]

    # Get file extension (also it's a suffix's value (i.e. ".20181231")) without dot
    date = os.path.splitext(filename)[1][1:]

    # Create new file name
    filename = os.path.join(log_directory, date)

    # I don't want to add index if only one log file will exists for date
    if not os.path.exists('{}.log'.format(filename)):
        return '{}.log'.format(filename)

    # Create new file name with index
    index = 0
    f = '{}.{}.log'.format(filename, index)
    while os.path.exists(f):
        index += 1
        f = '{}.{}.log'.format(filename, index)
    return f


format = u'%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(filename)s:%(lineno)d\t%(message)s'
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# new file every minute
rotation_logging_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('logs/log', 
                               when='m', 
                               interval=1, 
                               backupCount=5)
rotation_logging_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
rotation_logging_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(format))
rotation_logging_handler.suffix = '%Y%m%d'
rotation_logging_handler.namer = get_filename

logger.addHandler(rotation_logging_handler)
```

Comment: rotation_logging_handler.rotator = your_rotator_function() would also be helpful to rotate your log files with your customized filename format.